# With NodeMCU, how to read from console?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

Writing some lua libraries for NodeMCU. Would like to write test cases, but need to read / write to "console", ie, the terminal connection, in order to perform the tests.

The way ESPlorer is structured it might not be possible. Using minicom would be OK since only needed to run test suite.

For example:

```
= Hook LED to D1
= Hit Enter when done
>
= Did the LED come on? (y/n)
>
...
```

Anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Maybe you want to give the [NodeMCU mispec framework](https://github.com/luismfonseca/nodemcu-mispec) a try, looks really nice even though it doesn't read "from console"(never tried myself, though).

Comment: Why don't you communicate over WIFI? I'm sure you can come up with a web-console.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [node.input()](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/node/#nodeinput) and [node.output()](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/node/#nodeoutput) for that purpose.

Comment: not seeing how to capture something from the console. how would you do a `gets()`?